# provide a counterexample to $(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus C) \cup (C\setminus A) = A\cup B\cup C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

I know that the above statement is false, I just want to know how I should provide a counter example. For my work, I had originally let x be contained in  $(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus C) \cup (C\setminus A)$ and through set laws showed that $x$ cannot be in $A\cup B\cup C$ all at the same time. Could someone please work though a proof and explain the steps needed to show that the it is false. Thank you!

Comment: If you know a statement is false, then why is your title to "prove or provide a counterexample"?

Comment: The simplest way to check is to try an element that is in each of the eight possibilities for membership in $A,B,C$ and see if it comes out right.  By symmetry, you can just check the four cases of numbers of $A,B,C$ the element is in.  If not, you know what you need for a counterexample.  If it does, you have a proof.

Comment: It is a good practice to state the problem in the body of your Question, not only in the title as you've done here.  It might seem expeditious to compress the problem statement into the title and reference it thereafter in the body ("the above statement"), but this invites confusion on the part of Readers.  If you edit the Question, consider using the `\setminus` $\LaTeX$ operator which will produce a conventional "backslash" symbol (for relative set complement).

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=B=C=\{1\}$. Then $A\setminus B=B\setminus C=C\setminus A=\emptyset$ and so 
$$
(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus A)=\emptyset \neq \{1\}=A\cup B\cup C
$$